# Creating TouchMoveStart and TouchMoveStop methods

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm currently re-drawing polygons in my application each time the polygon is moved somewhere within the PreviewTouchMove method (from WPF). It is proving to be quite repetitive in terms of computational power. So I 'm thinking to just re-draw the polygon whenever it comes to a stop somewhere (that way I won't have to continuously draw it while it's moving).

**I want to detect when an object starts moving (by touch) and comes to a stop.** There seem to be no built-in methods for this type of calculation (there's just PreviewTouchUp and PreviewTouchDown which aren't related in this case).

Any tips regarding how I can implement my own methods to check for this would be much appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried Manipulation events? ManipulationStarted and ManipulationCompleted might be what you are looking for.

Comment: No I haven't tried those, I shall read about them now. Thank you :)

Comment: Don't forget to set IsManipulationEnabled to true on the objects that are going to add the events. Good luck! :)

Comment: I read about both ManipulationgStarted and ManipulationCompleted. I tried to implement them in my own application and came to a standstill. Do you think you could provide any sample code that makes use of them please?

Comment: Ah, Yes. `IsManipulationEnabled` set to `true` on the Parent somehow tends to block some other events on the Parent and the containing children. Do u get the control passed to the `ManipulationStarted` event? Well, I had a very good starting tutorial on MSDN that got me going on Manipulation events, but I cannot seem to find it now. I'm going to post a sample base code that I used in one of my touch applications for moving, resizing and rotating images.

Comment: I found the link. You can use this Walkthrough as a starting point for detecting start and completion of touch on your object. You can also use ManipulationDelta to get the touch details, and ManipulationCompleted to get the point where the touch event finished. Here is the link [Walkthrough: Creating Your First Touch Application](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ee649090(v=vs.100).aspx)

Comment: Thank you so much! I'll go through this and hopefully get a good understanding of it.